# Old alien sci-fi movie title

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a movie where a man was walking through the woods trailed by two men in suits. It seems that he is an alien and that he created this world, and then came to live in it - but that living in your created world is not allowed. At some point all the people kind of blinked out and turned to paper and wilted. Help please.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! Please try to add anything that may help identification. Review this [**checklist**](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question/9337#9337).  When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? What language? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions of scenes or characters you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. **You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title.**

Comment: Was it a short film, or full feature?